# Why doesn't the maven ear plugin include files I put in src/main/resources?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, ear

I have a dead simple pom:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sandbox</groupId>
    <name>Sandbox</name>
    <artifactId>Sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When the packaging is marked as "jar", it gets all the resources at src/main/resources.  But if the packaging is marked as "ear", it doesn't get any of those resources in the packaging.  The reason I want to do this is because I want a glassfish-resources.xml file to be in my ear's META-INF directory.  [This is a valid place to put the file.](https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/application_scoped_resources_in_glassfish)

Comment: have you tried putting it into src/main/webapp ?

Comment: @JoseM no, but an ear isn't necessarily a webapp.  Also, even webapps respect the src/main/resources directory.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268482/add-mf-xml-files-in-meta-inf-directory-inside-a-maven-built-ear

Comment: Ah according to that question, I can put it under "${basedir}/src/main/application/META-INF/"